# Build should trigger via PR in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request, multibranch-pipeline

we need to trigger the jenkins job in multibranch Pipeline (Jenkinsfile)
below points:

my multibranch detects 5 branches like 1,2,3,4,5 and master.(GITHUB)
Condition:

- Raise a PR for branch 1 and request for review, once review completed by approved, then build should be triggered.
- After approved the review, merge the branch1 in master then build should be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions), which would, when your criteria are matched, run a Jenkins job, using [`appleboy/jenkins-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/jenkins-action).

But that supposes your Jenkins can be seen by GitHub, which, for github.com, means your Jenkins is rechable through internet.
Not a good idea (for security reasons).

That approach is however more sensible if by "GitHub" you mean an on-premise GHE (GitHub for Enterprise).

If this is about github.com, then you need a [GitHub Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/), but it only deals with post-receive hook and also needs a public URL to contact your Jenkins.

You would need to develop a script to query GitHub event and check your PR review is in the required state: [`jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-github-plugin) could help.